# How do I configure how alerts display in JHipster?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jhipster, toastr

I'm using JHipster 2.19.0 and I like the new [AlertService](http://jhipster.github.io/using_angularjs.html#notification-system). However, I'd like to configure it so 1) alerts show up at the bottom of the screen and 2) they're full-width on mobile. Right now, alerts show up in the top left and they block access to most menu items. On mobile, they only take up 75% of the screen and sentences tend to wrap. I'd like to move alerts to the bottom right on desktop and have them take up 100% width on mobile.

I know this can probably be done with CSS, but I'm wondering if there's a different way. I've used [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) in the past and it has the ability to configure the directive if you're using [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster).

Comment: Matt, I definitely agree this can be much improved! Please add a ticket when you have something cool to show!

Comment: It looks like the current AlertService is based on UI Bootstrap alerts. Any objection to using AngularJS-Toaster instead?

Comment: No objection from me, but please add a ticket so Deepu (who coded this part) can have a look

Comment: Done: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1951

Comment: please see my comment in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/1953